# Stacktrace for failing tests on appharbor

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, specflow, appharbor

How do you get a stacktrace and debug logging when running SpecFlow tests on Appharbor?

The tests run but the only output I get is:

```
Status: Failed

Duration: 00:00:00.0312002

Message
TestFixtureSetUp failed in AdvertisementFeature
```

When I run it locally I get full stack trace and logging. I don't do any config file conversion at appharbor.

Comment: It's a known issue that we do not always display the stacktrace for all unit testing frameworks. If you open a support ticket, we might be able to pry it out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the full stacktrace for a SpecFlow test you will have to view the parent stacktrace, as SpecFlow log the stacktrace there. 
As for now the easiest way to view a parent test is to change the url to the parent url, by removing the last number, like in this example:

Failed test url: https://appharbor.com/applications/{applicationName}/builds/{buildId}/tests/1.1.2

Parent test url: https://appharbor.com/applications/{applicationName}/builds/{buildId}/tests/1.1